# Change QToolTip text color using style sheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qt6

I'm using Qt 6.5.2 on Windows 10.
I'm trying to change QToolTip's text color using stylesheet but no luck.

Here's what I've tried:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QLineEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QLineEdit *line_edit = new QLineEdit(this);
    line_edit->setToolTip("toolTip");
    line_edit->setStyleSheet("QToolTip"
                             "{"
                             "    border: none;"
                             "    padding: 2px;"
                             "    background-color: yellow;"
                             "    color: pink;"
                             "    font-size: 36px;"
                             "    font: bold;"
                             "}");
    this->setCentralWidget(line_edit);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work and how I can change the text color with style sheet?

Comment: Works for me. It doesn't seem to be the stylesheet...

Comment: Are you using Qt 6.5.2? It works for me also in Qt 5.15.2, and Qt 6.2.2 also. Seems to be a bug

Comment: Not reproducible on Linux (KDE Neon) using Qt 6.5.2 **/** 6.5.0 **/** 6.4.3 **/** 6.2.4. Probably an issue with Windows and Qt 6.5.2 combination.

Comment: This is reproducible on Qt 6.5.2 on Windows 11. It was not reproducible on Qt 5.15.2